# Improving handling of Express endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

I have an API gateway in a larger set of microservices, and I'm handling one of my routes. The endpoint ends up making an RPC call to another service, and then I just log the response and send it back to the user. I haven't really completed the error handling section, because was thinking that I could add some middleware later on to handle my errors.

```
routes.post("/submit", async (request, result) => {
  logger.info("Received call to /gapf/submit endpoint");
  const gapf = request.body;

  // convert relevant request strings into integers
  gapf.facultyId = parseInt(gapf.facultyId, 10);
  gapf.created = parseInt(gapf.created, 10);
  gapf.lastModified = parseInt(gapf.lastModified, 10);
  if (gapf.documents !== undefined) {
    gapf.documents = gapf.documents.map(doc => {
      return {
        name: doc.name,
        link: doc.link,
        attachedDate: parseInt(doc.attachedDate, 10)
      };
    });
  }

  try {
    logger.info("Calling to Ticket Service with gapf body: %j", gapf);
    const response = await tridentClient.SubmitGAPF(gapf);
    logger.info("Received response from Ticket Service: %j", response);
    logger.info("Exiting /gapf/submit endpoint");
    result.json(response);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(
      "Received error from submitting to Ticket Service: ",
      err.message
    );
    // TODO: should add middleware later on to handle errors
    result.status(500);
    result.json({});
  }
});
```

Right now the `error.message` seems to be some binary data instead of `JSON`, so that would also need to be fixed later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the first issue below, your code is mostly clean!

- What happens if one of the `parseInt` calls throws an exception? In that case, I'd send a `HTTP 500` error as well. This is especially relevant in your scenario where the data comes from an unknown client.
  Essentially, the solution boils down to wrapping all the code in a `try-catch` or employing middleware.

  ```
  routes.post("/submit", async (request, result) => {
    try {
      /* all the code */
    }
    catch (err) {
      /* log & send a generic HTTP 500 error message as in your code */
      /* Beware that you might not intend to send a HTTP 500 message if
         the code in the try already sent something! */
    }
  });

  // <=>
  routes.post("/submit", wrapSafe(yourCodeExtractedAsAFunction));

  // <=>
  routes.post("/submit", someMiddleWare(yourCodeAsAFunction));
  ```
- Catching all exceptions (and not rethrowing ones you cannot handle) is fine in your case since your function is top-level enough for that.
  Exactly as you say, if you add middleware, let the exception bubble up and let the middleware take care of it.
- Omit the `return` in an arrow function if it is unnecessary and serves no clarity. So this block:

  > ```
  > gapf.documents = gapf.documents.map(doc => {
  >   return {
  >     name: doc.name,
  >     link: doc.link,
  >     attachedDate: parseInt(doc.attachedDate, 10)
  >   };
  > });
  > ```

  Can be updated like this:

  ```
  // You need enclosing parentheses, so that the parser can
  // differentiate between a block statement and an object literal.
  gapf.documents = gapf.documents.map(doc => ({
    name: doc.name,
    link: doc.link,
    attachedDate: parseInt(doc.attachedDate, 10)
  }));
  ```
- `// convert relevant request strings into integers`: Maybe you could describe what constitutes a "relevant request string". Is there a list of them?